# Android Studio how to make WebView supports to the Arabic Language i.e., RTL text Direction?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview

I am using webview in android to display terms and conditions , but the issue is I need to make application supports for Arabic language. Here it required make the text direction Right to Left (RTL). But I followed lot ways to solve this. Can you please check the ways and suggest me once.

**Process One**

```java
private String mUrl="terms_conditions_url";

WebView webview=findViewById(R.id.web_view);



if(ltrDirection){
```

/**
    For LTR text
    */

```
webView.loadData(mUrl);

}else{
```

/**
    For RTL text
    */

```
 mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mURL,"<html><body dir=\"rtl\"></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
```

**Process Two**
And also I followed another way it is like..,

```java
private String mUrl="terms_conditions_url";

WebView webview=findViewById(R.id.web_view);


if(ltrDirection){
```

/**
    For LTR text
    */

```
webView.loadData(mUrl);

}else{
```

/**
    For RTL text
    */

```
 mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mURL,"<html dir=\"rtl\"></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
```

But nothing is worked for me.

Please give me the best code for it.

Comment: is your Terms and Condition a text value or is it present on the webpage?

Comment: Nothing worked because loadBataWithBaseURL*  takes a String data as its parameter! If terms and condition is a hardcoded string value then add it as a String datatype like String value = "your_terms_connditions"

Comment: @PrajwalW It's Present on webPage.

Comment: you need to make changes on the webpage then as far as i know. And if that is the case then you cant really use any of the above mentioned code of yours!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code! updated!

```
    WebView wv;
        String outhtml = "Terms and Condition are as follows....your strings";

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_test);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(mURL, "<html dir=\"rtl\" lang=\"\"><body>" + outhtml + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```